# How to give culture info to the compare validator for currency?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My asp.net application has more than one textbox which for currency inputs. So I add compare validator programmatically to the application. I have to allow only US currency format then I do it with Thread culture info and works fine. But Page culture info must not effected this culture info. For example; when user entered from US, page labels and validation errors must showed in English language and when user entered from Turkey page language must showed in Turkish language. But when I give Thread culture info to my compare validator class,  compare validator currency format is US (which is fine) and validation errors are also English (which is not fine and must showed as page language). How do I seperate currency culture info and error message culture info? My code:

Validator.cs

```
public class Validator
{
    public Validator()
    {
        CultureInfo Cul = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Cul;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Cul;
    }

    public CompareValidator CreateCompareValidator(string id, string validationGroup, string controlToValidate, bool enableClientScript, string errorMessage)
    {
        CompareValidator compareValidator = new CompareValidator();
        compareValidator.ID = id;
        compareValidator.ValidationGroup = validationGroup;
        compareValidator.ControlToValidate = controlToValidate;
        compareValidator.Operator = ValidationCompareOperator.DataTypeCheck;
        compareValidator.Type = ValidationDataType.Currency;
        compareValidator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.None;
        compareValidator.EnableClientScript = enableClientScript;
        compareValidator.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        compareValidator.CultureInvariantValues = true;

        return compareValidator;
    }
}
```

name.aspx.cs

```
 private void ValidateCurrencyTextBox()
    {
        AddValidator(txtBaTutar.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());
        AddValidator(txtBsTutar.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());

        AddValidator(txtBpbBakiye1.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());
        AddValidator(txtBpbBakiye2.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());
        AddValidator(txtBpbBakiye3.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());
        AddValidator(txtBpbBakiye4.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());
        AddValidator(txtBpbBakiye5.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());

        AddValidator(txtTRYBakiye1.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());
        AddValidator(txtTRYBakiye2.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());
        AddValidator(txtTRYBakiye3.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());
        AddValidator(txtTRYBakiye4.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());
        AddValidator(txtTRYBakiye5.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());

        AddValidator(txtVergiMatrahi.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());
        AddValidator(txtVergiTutari.ID, GetLocalResourceObject("bsWrongAmount").ToString());
    }

    private void AddValidator(string controlToValidate, string errorMessage)
    {
        Validator validator = new Validator();
        CompareValidator cmp = validator.CreateCompareValidator("cmpv" + controlToValidate, "errors", controlToValidate, false, errorMessage);
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(cmp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using just CurrentCulture for the currency, and using CurrentUICulture for the page language.